# json.dump python mysql result

Tags: python, mysql, json

I use python and mySql, run the query below:

```
sSql = "select id from table_name"
cursor.execute( sSql )
lrec = self.cursor.fetchall()
json.dumps( lrec )
```

and get an error message because I get back long int notation `'id' : 1L` instead of `'id' : 1`

the only way to work around this I found to be is ugly:

```
sSql = "select cast(id as char(10)) as id from table_name"
```

Any better way of doing it?

Thanks,
 Juergen

Comment: What does your lrec look like when you print it?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What you "get back" from `fetchall` is a value, not a notation.  The value can contain longs, admitted.  What you "get back" from `dumps` is a string, so that can contain a notation like `1L`.  Which is it?

Comment: pp.pprint in first case: `[{ 'id': 1L}]` and `[{ 'id': '1'}]` in second. first is no valid JSON of course and json.dumps breaks. Also in case of dates I get e.g. `'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 2, 9, 18, 38)`. Ideally I could tell json.dumps to evaluate to strings, booleans and ints to make it valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over lrec and convert all the `id`'s to `int`. I don't know how your lrec is formatted (i.e. a list of tuples).

```
no_longs = [int(my_id) for my_id in lrec]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply John, interesting idea to "massage" the result; only if you want to make it generic, i.e. to deal with `select *` one needs to identify types... still better than my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to johnthexiii's hint I decided to simply modify the result before json.dumping.
I however convert everything to string since the consumer of the JSON knows how to process certain variables and can work with strings only.
By so doing I also avoid the issue with date fields which return e.g. `datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 2, 9, 18, 38)`

```
ltpv = [ tpv for tpv in self.cursor ]
lk = [ ltpk[ 0 ] for ltpk in self.cursor.description ]
laResults = []
for tpv in ltpv:
    aResult = {}
    for k, v in zip( lk, tpv ):
        aResult[ k ] = unicode( v )
    laResults.append( aResult )
json.dumps( laResults )
```

Thanks all for the input